# PopUp window with no address bar

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, popup

I seem to remember reading that modern browsers try to stop the hiding of the address bar of a popup window, but there were ways around this..

Currently I'm using this code :

```
<script language="javascript">
    var popupWindow = null;
    function centeredPopup(url,winName,w,h,scroll){
        LeftPosition = (screen.width) ? (screen.width-w)/2 : 0;
        TopPosition = (screen.height) ? (screen.height-h)/2 : 0;
        settings = 'height='+h+',width='+w+',top='+TopPosition+',left='+LeftPosition+',scrollbars='+scroll+',resizable'
        popupWindow = window.open(url,winName,settings)
    }
</script>

<img onClick="centeredPopup('test.php','test','400','400','yes');return false" src="test.png">
```

In Safari it works great the popup shows with no address bar, but in Chrome, IE11 and Firefox the address bar is shown.

Is there anyway this can work with out the address bar in all the browsers I've listed, or can it be done using other code ? javascript, jquery, php ?

All I'm after is a simple popup that starts at a specific size, but is moveable, resizeable and scrollable if needed.

Thanks

**** UPDATE ****

I have this sort of working. The dialog appears with scroll bars but I can't scroll.

Any ideas ? This **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BU98r/)** shows what I mean.

Comment: You can make use of https://jqueryui.com/dialog for implementing simple popup that starts at a specific size, is moveable, realizable and scrollable..

Comment: Thanks can this load an external page and be called from an image link ?

Comment: Find the answer to your query below.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm getting something wrong, but just in case: The Fiddle you provided has set scrolling to "no" in the html. Once its set to "yes", its scrolling perfectly :)

```
<div id="dialog" style="display:none;" title="Dialog Title"><iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" width="100%" height="100%" src="http://google.about.com/"></iframe></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do something similar:

```
<a class="test" href="www.somesite.com">Test</a> 
<div id="somediv-wrap">
  <div id="somediv">

  </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {  

        $("#somediv-wrap").dialog({
                  autoOpen: false,
                   width: 400, 
                   height:200,
                   modal: true
                  });  

        $(".test").click(function(event)
          {
              event.preventDefault();
              var link = $(this).attr('href');

              $("#somediv").load(link,function(){
               $( "#somediv-wrap" ).dialog( "open" );   
              });                        
      });
   });
</script>
```

You create your dialog, and when it is opened, an html file is loaded from your server, replacing the contents of your `<div id="somediv"></div>`, which should be inside your dialog `<div class="somediv-wrap"/>`.

Comment: Thanks - sorry I should have said the page I want to load is local. I've tried editing this and it doesn't seem to want to load it. also I get what appears to be an overlay showing, I don't need that I want the user to be able to interact with the page and have the popup visible. Thx